# What is the best way to limit results using a DetachedCriteria of Hibernate in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, detachedcriteria

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.6-Final in Java. Since I don't have access to the Hibernate [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html), I'm using a [DetachedCriteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html). So, I would like to know **what is the best way to limit the results for a DetachedCriteria** (in my case I would like to get only the first row).

*Additional info:*

The [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) class has some methods to achieve this, like [setMaxResults(int maxResults)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setMaxResults%28int%29) or [setFirstResult(int firstResult)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setFirstResult%28int%29), but the DetachedCriteria doesn't have neither. Again, I can't use the Criteria because I don't have access to the Hibernate's Session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how i am doing it, you have to wrap your result into execute block. 
EntityMAnager in the example below is `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOperations` object :

```
final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ActivePropertyView.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("featured", true));
List<ActivePropertyView> result = entityManager.execute(
     new HibernateCallback<List<ActivePropertyView>>() {
         @Override
         public List<ActivePropertyView> doInHibernate(Session session) 
                                         throws HibernateException,SQLException {
                 return criteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).setMaxResults(5).list();
         }
     });
return result;
```

Comment: It seems like this approach is the best because the `DetachedCriteria` will always arrive at the repository layer where the _Hibernate Session_ is. Thanks!

Comment: This one will work fine only when it has single object. What if this detached object is having association and that association is have multiple records. This MaxResults(1) is getting only associated object even it has more results

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Restrictions.sqlRestriction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String%29) add plain SQL expression to DetachedCriteria. Try this:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Domain.class)
  .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("LIMIT 1"));
```

Comment: this is not working in mysql case. I observed that 'limit 1'  shown as condition in WHERE clause which is not a valid sql statement.

Comment: A workaround is to put `DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Domain.class)
  .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("1=1 LIMIT 1"));`

Comment: At least PostgreSQL requires `LIMIT` statement to be physically behind `ORDER BY`. This approach insert it between `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, if you specified one. But if you didn't order your results, how can you get consistent results?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using hibernate templates, there is a `findByCriteria(criteria, firstResult, maxResults)`. Templates are discouraged, but for those with legacy code this is available.

Comment: best answer ever

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading the javadoc right, you cannot limit until you finally convert the DetachedCriteria to a real Criteria (when you do have a Session)

Comment: Thanks for amending my blocking point, but I still would like to know _how to do it_. Seems like the answer given by @iririr is the best approach by the moment to handle this scenario.

Comment: Why not use your own ExtendedDetachedCriteriaClass that extends Criteria and adds limit and offset. Then set those when you actually have the session.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on yorkw's answer, the Oracle equivalent is:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Domain.class)
  .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("rownum < 1"));
```

It will add the row limit to the "where" clause in the subquery.

Answer (score -1):

```
detachedCriteria.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).setMaxResults(1);
```